# VLOOKUP for 2 queries in different locations (INDEX + MATCH?)

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I've been using `VLOOKUP` quite a bit and has been very helpful, however I've been searching around for a method to do the same thing with two or more queries

I have attampted to this this below, but have had no luck

```
=INDEX(A1:A40,MATCH(1,(A1:A34="East")*(D1:D40="Points"),0))
```

I have uploaded a picture of the data

```
If Cell = East & (9 rows below) = "Points"
```

then add points up

http://postimg.org/image/k00bs80il/

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to add the points up for all the East matches, so in your picture, you want to get 9?

`SUMIFS` seems to be your best bet.

```
=SUMIFS(A11:A33,A2:A24,"East",D11:D33,"Points")
```

A couple of things to be careful:

The 'height' of the ranges need to be the same:

- The sum is 23 rows high;
- The first criteria range is 23 rows high;
- The second criteria range is 23 rows high.